# how to specify more than one authenticated guard in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, guard

i'm reading in Authentication section in laravel website https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

can anyone explain how I can do this , like the documentation explains , to specify separate tables for authentication ... i will quotes from laravel like below :

> **Accessing Specific Guard Instances**
>
> You may specify which guard instance you would like to utilize using
>   the **guard** method on the **Auth** facade. This allows you to manage
>   authentication for separate parts of your application using entirely
>   separate authenticatable models or user tables.
>
> The guard name passed to the **guard** method should correspond to one of
>   the guards configured in your **auth.php** configuration file:

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You kinda have to read the examples of adding custom guards and providers, the configuration part of it mainly. You can use the same auth 'driver', you just want to adjust what model is used by the Auth user provider.

`config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    // add another one
    // use the same driver, 'session', but a different user provider
    'admin' => [
         'driver' => 'session',
         'provider' => 'admins',
     ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    // add a provider using Eloquent but using a different model
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
]
```

Then you should be able to specify the guard `admin` to Auth. As long as that `Admin` model implements Authenticatable and you are passing the appropriate credentials to `attempt` on Auth you should be good.

Comment: thanks you so much :)  @lagbox  ,,, i will try this as you mentioned  , and let you know , have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

If you have more middlewares and you want to apply more than one guard and by this i mean middleware you can do this in any Middleware.php file:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // if a user is Agency or Admin, let him through
    if (Auth::user()->isAgency() || Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    } 
    // else show error page
    abort(403);
}
```

Comment: there is only one guard being used in this example, the default.

Comment: Ok. ..just wanted to contribute

Comment: no problem, i often use the approach of admin just being a flag on the users table, as opposed to a seperate table, and this example setup would work nice for that :-)

Comment: well ... the idea of my question is to implement authentication manually ,,, I don't want to make it nested questions here , but I did as u mentioned , and added  the "auth" middleware to my routes , but it's return me again to login ,, i debug it ,, i see that the guard which i passes to auth middleware is null ?? any idea about that @ lagbox

Comment: You need to create both functions isAdmin() and isAgency() in your model